# Google Visualizations and CSS grid heights

Tags: css, google-visualization, css-grid

I'd like to have a css grid that uses height and width as percentages to allow it to fit any size browser.  The problem is that two of my cells contain Google visualizations.

Google visualizations have the ability to take on the height and width of their container, if you give them the options

```
var options = {width: '100%', height: '100%'}
var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('source_table_div'));
chart.draw(data, options)
```

The problem is that if I do that with no minimum size, then the visualization doesn't draw at all, and the same thing happens with

```
min-height: 100%;
```

as well.  If I hard-code a min-height using pixels, though, I can see something:

```
min-height: 500px;
```

But it never resizes to the maximum size of the cell, only the minimum - meaning I can't change the height to fit the page.

I know I can do @media queries but I'd have to make thousands of them to fit every contingency.

How can I do this without 1000 @media queries?

Adding my stylesheet and page for WhiteHat.

Style:

```
<style>

#full_page_grid_container {
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 45% 10% 45%;
  grid-template-rows:    10% 10% 40% 40%;
  grid-template-areas:   "header        header       header" 
                         "source_search .            target_search" 
                         "source_table  right_button target_table" 
                         "source_table  left_button  target_table";
}

#full_page_grid_container div {
  border-style: solid;
}

h1 {
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
}

#source_table_div {
  grid-area: source_table;
  min-height: 700px;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#target_table_div {
  grid-area: target_table;
}

.title {
  grid-area: header;
}

.link_home {
  grid-area: header;
}


</style>
```

and page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('AddCrewStylesheet'); ?>
    <?var url = getScriptUrl();?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
      function drawTable() {
        var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I3N5DtdXGWFootaOCQM201K_ao2ZPWSWyw9_l7QcwQg/gviz/tq?sheet=Crew_Basics');
        query.send(handleQueryResponse);
      }

      function handleQueryResponse(response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
          alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
          return;
        }
         var data = response.getDataTable();
        var options = {width: '100%', height: '100%'}

        var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('source_table_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options)
      }
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="full_page_grid_container">
      <div class="title"><h1>Select Your Crew</h1></div>
      <div class="link_home"><a href="<?=url?>">Return Home</a><br /></div>
      <div id="source_table_div" class="google_table"></div>
      <div id="target_table_div" class="google_table"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: not following the question exactly, is there an example you can provide? are you trying to resize the chart or the chart's container? would recommend setting the chart size to always be 100% of the container, then resize the container as needed. note: if the size changes, the chart must be re-drawn...

Comment: I do currently set the chart size to be 100% of the container.  It's just that it's not drawing unless I specify a min-height in pixels.

Comment: @WhiteHat added the code for the two pages to my OP

Comment: I must be missing something, check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8qgkwma/), if I set `min-height: 100%;` on `#source_table_div` it draws fine, just need to scroll towards the bottom to see...

Comment: hmm.. doesn't on mine... maybe a browser difference?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Firefox.  In Chrome I get what you describe, although that behavior is very much still not what I'm aiming for, hah.